# Convert a list to a string list python

Tags: python, string, list

I'm Python beginner can't get my head around. How do I change 
for example `a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`
into `"12\n34\n56"` string format.

This is as far as i got but it goes into newline with each number.

```
def change(a):
    c = ""
    for r in a:
        for b in r:
            c += str(b) + "\n"
    return c
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`str.join`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
>>> a = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
>>> '\n'.join(''.join(map(str, xs)) for xs in a)
'12\n34\n56'
```

Comment: Just curious, why do you `map(str, xs)` instead of just `str(xs)`? Isn't the latter cheaper?

Comment: @Lawrence, `str(xs)` results in `'[1, 2]'`, while `''.join(map(str, [1, 2]))` gives you `12`.

Comment: Right, I missed the fact that `xs` is in fact a list :)

Answer (score 12):

> but it goes into newline with each number

That’s because you add the newline after *each number* instead of after each sublist `r`. If you want that instead, you should append the newline there:

```
c = ''
for r in a:
    for b in r:
        c += str(b)
    c += '\n'
return c
```

But note that appending to a string is very inefficient, as it ends up creating lots of intermediary strings. Usually, you would create a list instead to which you append your string parts, and then finally join that list to convert it to a single string:

```
c = []
for r in a:
    for b in r:
        c.append(str(b))
    c.append('\n')
return ''.join(c)
```

And then, you can also use list expressions to make this shorter in multiple steps; first for the inner list:

```
c = []
for r in a:
    c.extend([str(b) for b in r])
    c.append('\n')
return ''.join(c)
```

And you can join that list comprehension first:

```
c = []
for r in a:
    c.append(''.join([str(b) for b in r]))
    c.append('\n')
return ''.join(c)
```

Then you can move the newline into the outer join, and make a new list comprehension for the outer list:

```
c = [''.join([str(b) for b in r]) for r in a]
return '\n'.join(c)
```

And at that point, you can make it a one-liner too:

```
return '\n'.join([''.join([str(b) for b in r]) for r in a])
```

As Padraic pointed out in the comments, joining on the newline character will also prevent the string from having a trailing `\n` which you would end up if you kept adding it in the loop. Otherwise, you could have used `str.rstrip('\n')` to get rid of it afterwards.

Comment: Tnx so much nice explanation! :)

Comment: I'd go with the slightly more verbose version that uses list comprehensions: `'\n'.join([''.join([str(v) for v in u]) for u in a])`. The generator version looks neater, but the list comp has less overhead. And there's no advantage to passing a gen exp to `join` since it needs all the substrings before it starts work (otherwise there'd be no advantage in using `join()` over simple string concatenation).

Comment: Your code actually gives the wrong result, I had an answer I deleted as you had answered first but you need to remove the last newline or keep a check on where you are and not add a newline if you are at the last grouping

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: +1. Or just use the `join`-based approach, so you don't get the unwanted trailing `\n`. Alternatively, just use slicing to remove the trailing `\n` from the string... but that's a bit messy.

Comment: @PM2Ring, yep join is certainly the solution to use, I just meant if you were to actually use a loop then that is something you have to catch.